# How does MinIO replicate compressed objects

Tags: minio

I am trying to better understand how [server-side bucket replication](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/replication/replication-overview.html#minio-bucket-replication-serverside) works w.r.t to [compressed objects](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-compression-guide.html). Seemingly, MinIO does not (yet) support compressed transfer between client and server (https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/6880).

I'm storing large text data (~1 GB per object) in MinIO. The server is configured to store these objects compressed on disk. The compressed objects are just about 1/10 in size.

Now, I'm wondering how these objects are replicated. Does MinIO use a lower level protocol to replicate nodes that transfer the already compressed objects as they are?

Or are they uncompressed, transferred, and then compressed again as if replicated by using the regular client API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the option of uploading compressed object to MinIO server or utilizing the server side compression feature.
W.r.t replication, if the object was compressed before upload to the primary server, this would be replicated as compressed to the replication target.

However, if you are using server side compression, the data will be uncompressed and transferred to the target - there is no assumption made that the replication target has compression enabled. You will have to independently enable compression on primary and target

Please know you can find us at https://slack.min.io/ 24/7/365. If you have commercial questions, please reach out to us on hello@min.io or on our Ask an Expert Chat functionality at https://min.io/pricing?action=talk-to-us.